# FizzBuzz using switches

Tags: java, beginner, fizzbuzz

I'm learning about control structures now, and I want to see if I'm doing this as cleanly and efficiently as possible. Seems like there should be a less... verbose way of writing the `switch` but I wouldn't know what it is. Any criticism welcome!

**FizzBuzz.java**

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    public static final int fizz = 3;
    public static final int buzz = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int status = -1;        

        for (int fbNumber = 1; fbNumber <= 100; fbNumber++) {

            if ((fbNumber % fizz == 0) && (fbNumber % buzz == 0)) {
                status = 1;
            } else if ((fbNumber % fizz == 0) && (fbNumber % buzz != 0)) {
                status = 2;
            } else if ((fbNumber % fizz != 0) && (fbNumber % buzz == 0)) {
                status = 3;
            } else {
                status = 4;
            }
            switch (status) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Fizz");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Buzz");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println(fbNumber);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Number could not be evaluated");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not enough factories!

Comment: So I'm a little annoyed that no one has yet suggested taking advantage of fallthrough, given that the question is about a "less verbose `switch`"...  Don't have time to write up an answer now, though maybe later tonight if no one has since added one

Comment: @Izkata, the fall-through behavior of switches makes code harder to read and understand, and should be avoided because it will increase the chance of bugs. It's better to factor out repetitive blocks of code into functions.

Comment: @zzzzBov Yeah, I had to think about it a bit after making the comment (forgot to come back until now), but the particular feature I had in mind is from a different language (but would have been easier to read).  Tiredness made me not realize it wouldn't transfer over to Java nicely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the thing. When you see

```
switch (status) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    default:
}
```

what do you *know*? What does `case 1` mean? Is `1` even a sensible `status`?

The same thing applies with

```
status = 1;
status = 2;
status = 3;
status = 4;
```

It's just not a meaningful thing to write.

There's also:

```
public static final int fizz = 3;
public static final int buzz = 5;
```

Although this *kind of* makes sense, it doesn't *really* make sense. Fizz isn't 3. 3 is just the factor that *triggers* "Fizz" in the output.

You should really be encapsulating the state not over the result (`FizzBuzz`/`Fizz`/`Buzz`/`n`) but over the input (`Fiz`/`Not Fizz`, `Buzz`/`Not Buzz`). Java doesn't have tuples, so let's use `javafx.util.Pair<Boolean, Boolean>`, and give it a loose abstraction:

```
public static class IsFizzOrBuzz extends Pair<Boolean, Boolean> {
    public IsFizzOrBuzz(boolean isFizz, boolean isBuzz) {
        super(isFizz, isBuzz);
    }

    public boolean isFizz() { return getKey(); };
    public boolean isBuzz() { return getValue(); };
}
```

Unfortunately you can't do `case` on objects, so the de-facto alternative is a hash map

```
static public Map<IsFizzOrBuzz, String> responses;
static {
    responses = new HashMap<IsFizzOrBuzz, String>();
    responses.put(new IsFizzOrBuzz(true,  true),  "FizzBuzz");
    responses.put(new IsFizzOrBuzz(true,  false), "Fizz");
    responses.put(new IsFizzOrBuzz(false, true),  "Buzz");
    responses = Collections.unmodifiableMap(responses);
}
```

Then the proper abstraction looks like

```
public static int FIZZ_FACTOR = 3;
public static int BUZZ_FACTOR = 5;

public static IsFizzOrBuzz classify(int n) {
    return new IsFizzOrBuzz(n % FIZZ_FACTOR == 0, n % BUZZ_FACTOR == 0);
}

public static String getResponse(int n, IsFizzOrBuzz classification) {
    if (responses.containsKey(classification)) {
        return responses.get(classification);
    }

    return String.valueOf(n);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(getResponse(i, classify(i)));
    }
}
```

I'm going to be honest, though. Although this works quite well in a concise language:

```
fizz_factor = 3
buzz_factor = 5

responses = {
    (True,  True):  "FizzBuzz",
    (True,  False): "Fizz",
    (False, True):  "Buzz"
}

def classify(n):
    return (n % fizz_factor == 0, n % buzz_factor == 0)

def get_response(n, classification):
    return responses.get(classification, str(n))

def main():
    for i in range(1, 101):
        print(get_response(i, classify(i)))

main()
```

in Java can you really call this worthwhile? You end up fighting the language most of the time. A simple

```
class FizzBuzz {
    public static int FIZZ_FACTOR = 3;
    public static int BUZZ_FACTOR = 5;

    public static String getFizzBuzzResponse(int n) {
        if ((n % FIZZ_FACTOR == 0) && (n % BUZZ_FACTOR == 0)) {
            return "FizzBuzz";
        }

        if (n % FIZZ_FACTOR == 0) {
            return "Fizz";
        }

        if (n % BUZZ_FACTOR == 0) {
            return "Buzz";
        }

        return String.valueOf(n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(getFizzBuzzResponse(i));
        }
    }
}
```

is easy enough. YAGNI.

Comment: Lots of great answers but yours feels the most thorough and useful for a beginner. Thanks for the great (now accepted) answer!

Answer (score 15):

Constants `fizz` and `buzz` should be `ALL_CAPS`, by convention.

The use of `status` and the `switch` is unjustified.  Why complicate things by setting a variable to alter behaviour a few lines later?

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    public static final int FIZZ = 3;
    public static final int BUZZ = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int fbNumber = 1; fbNumber <= 100; fbNumber++) {

            if ((fbNumber % FIZZ == 0) && (fbNumber % BUZZ == 0)) {
                System.out.println("FizzBuzz");
            } else if ((fbNumber % FIZZ == 0) && (fbNumber % BUZZ != 0)) {
                System.out.println("Fizz");
            } else if ((fbNumber % FIZZ != 0) && (fbNumber % BUZZ == 0)) {
                System.out.println("Buzz");
            } else {
                System.out.println(fbNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer surely simplifies things, but it also goes to the wrong direction: You're **mixing computation and output**, which makes it completely non-reusable. Imagine you should process the output before writing it out.

Comment: @maaartinus There was actually no maintainability benefit to separating computation and presentation using a switch. You could, for example, call `fizzbuzzWriter.writeFizz()` to accomplish that without the awkwardness of setting a four-valued flag variable. And `FizzbuzzWriter` would actually be a modular, swappable part.

Comment: I fully agree that switch makes little sense here. A method like `fizzBuzzString` plus a printing loop is perfect, IMHO. A `java.io.Writer` (if you mean it by `FizzbuzzWriter`) goes probably too far (especially for a beginner).

Comment: The if conditions can be simplified per nhgrif

Comment: @200_success Using an enum and returning that from its own method seems actually like a perfectly acceptable compromise between maintainability and complexity.

Comment: @Voo I'm not a fan of using an enum at all for this application. I would consider a switch statement too much like a [code smell](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/690082/Code-Smells-Switch-and-If-Statements).

Comment: @200_success It's pretty much the same amount of effort as the code you posted, is relatively easy to maintain, extend and read. Now you can go for a command pattern and throw in a few factories if you're at it, but realistically that's overkill.

Comment: @Voo Defining an enum, setting the flag, and acting on the flag spreads out the logic in three different places. A `FizzBuzzOutputStream` doesn't have that problem, and therefore it wouldn't be more code. In any case, why are we discussing a solution that I didn't actually recommend in my answer?

Answer (score 12):

Well, this immediately jumps out at me.

What does your `status` mean?

We should use some sort of `enumeration` or at least defined constants to give these statuses names.  That will save a lot of maintenance time.  Instead of having to read your code to determine what each scenario is, I can just read the variable name where it says: `case kStatusFizzBuzz`.

```
public enum FBStatus {
    FBStatusFizzBuzz,
    FBStatusFizz,
    FBStatusBuzz,
    FBStatusNone,
    FBStatusUnknown
}
```

And declare your variable as type `FBStatus`, initialized to `FBStatusUnknown`.

---

We shouldn't clutter the `main` function.  We should be writing other methods and passing the work out to them.

For example, we might have one method which simply takes an integer, any integer, and returns the appropriate fizz buzz string.

And another method that serves as our test method, which takes a starting number, and a stopping number, and prints the result of the first method for each value.

Now all main has to do is call the testing method for the expected range.

For example:

```
public static String fizzBuzzString(int fbNumber) {
    // return appropriate string
}

public static void fizzBuzzTest(int start, int stop) {
    for (int i = start; i <= stop; ++i) {
        System.out.println(fizzBuzzString(i));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    fizzBuzzTest(1,100);
}
```

---

It should also be noted that in your `if-else` chain, you're doing some unnecessary checking:

```
if ((fbNumber % fizz == 0) && (fbNumber % buzz == 0)) { // condition 1
    status = 1;
} else if ((fbNumber % fizz == 0) && (fbNumber % buzz != 0)) { // condition 2
    status = 2;
} else if ((fbNumber % fizz != 0) && (fbNumber % buzz == 0)) { // condition 3
    status = 3;
} else {  // condition 4
    status = 4;
}
```

Notice how in condition 4, we don't have to check for `(fbNumber % fizz != 0) && (fbNumber % buzz != 0)`?  Why?  It's because condition 4 only happens if nothing else happened.

So with that said, if we make it past condition 1, we know that `fbNumber % fizz` is non-zero or `fbNumber % buzz` is non-zero, but definitely not both.  So in condition 2, if `fbNumber % fizz == 0` evaluates to `true`, then we know the second half (`fbNumber % buzz != 0`) will always be true, because otherwise, we would've jumped into condition 1.

We can rewrite this `if-else` chain as such:

```
if ((fbNumber % fizz == 0) && (fbNumber % buzz == 0)) {
    status = 1;
} else if (fbNumber % fizz == 0) {
    status = 2;
} else if (fbNumber % buzz == 0) {
    status = 3;
} else {
    status = 4;
}
```

Comment: As a disclaimer, I basically never write Java... so take this all with a grain of salt.  The core ideas here should be sound even if there's some Java-specific inaccuracies.

Comment: Contrary to the ole' horrible C enums that pollute the global namespace, Java's enums don't, so prefixing everything with the enum name just duplicates it. Also I see no reason to have an unknown state there in any case.

Comment: I'd prefix it for readability... But that may not be Java practice.

Comment: You are referring to an enum in java with its qualified name (except if you do static imports, but that's hardly a great idea in general). I don't see how `FBStatus.FBStatusFizz` is more readable than `FBStatus.Fizz`.

Comment: I thought when I saw an example of Java enums, the name wasn't qualified... But if it is, then I'd agree with your point.

Comment: It's not qualified in switches (which is where you'd often see them), but in that case you know it's a `FBStatus` because you're switching on a variable of that type - although I guess I could see the reasoning there.

Answer (score 8):

If we gradually eliminate some bad practices,
or replace some techniques with better ones,
then we can naturally arrive at something better. Let's go.

---

It's good to minimize the scope of variables as much as possible.
Most notably in this example,
the `status` variable is not used outside the body of the `for` loop,
therefore it should be declared inside.

So instead of this:

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     int status = -1;        
>
>     for (int fbNumber = 1; fbNumber <= 100; fbNumber++) {
> ```

This is better:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int fbNumber = 1; fbNumber <= 100; fbNumber++) {
        int status = -1;
```

In this form, the variable `status` doesn't exist outside the `for` loop,
which protects you from mistakenly reusing it where it was not intended.

This technique also reduces the *live time* of the variable.
The live time is the number of lines between the first and last reference to a variable.
The shorter the live time,
the smaller the mental burden it takes to understand the variable,
and the smaller the window where it might be misused.

---

Notice that the initialization `status = -1` is unnecessary,
because the `if-then-else` will always assign a value to it.
So you can drop the pointless initialization,
simply declare it without assignment:

```
int status;
```

---

There are more problems with `status`:

1. You set it to values 1, 2, 3, 4, which by themselves don't carry any meaning.
   Looking at the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, it's impossible to guess what they stand for,
   which is less than ideal in a program,
   and can easily lead to bugs.
2. After setting `status` in the `if-else`, you do a `switch`, which is a roughly equivalent operation, duplicating the effect of the earlier `if-else`. I think there's a term for this: `status` is a *phony variable* just for the sake of using in a `switch`, without a real functional purpose. (Notice the name "status" lacks a good functional meaning.)
3. The place in the code where you act on the different values of `status` is a couple of lines apart from the place where you set its value. This hurts readability: if I want to verify the connection between the action on a value and how that value was set, my eyes have to jump between the `if-then-else` block and the `switch` block.

In short, it would have been better to not use `status` at all:
it caused more problems than it solved.

---

Applying the above changes we more or less arrive at the suggestion of [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success), without a `switch`. This is not a good example case for using `switch`.

Answer (score 7):

You could simplify this a little more by having a value for `fizzbuzz`:

```
public static final int fizzbuzz = fizz * buzz;
```

Thus, your first check will be simplified as such:

```
if (fbNumber % fizzbuzz == 0) {
    status = 1;
```

This may also be useful in case you decide to increase the number of different strings to be outputted.  Instead of increasing the length of your first check, you'll just increase the value of `fizzbuzz` along with changing the variable name.

Answer (score 4):

**A `switch` is not warranted in this situation**

Let's consider the problem: we have a collection of conditions. For each number, we want to test whether each condition matches the current number. For each matching condition, we output some magic value.

If there are no conditions that match, then output the original number.

The way to do this is to use an `enum`:

```
static enum FizzBuzz implements IntFunction<Boolean> {
    FIZZ(i -> i % 3 == 0, "Fizz"),
    BUZZ(i -> i % 5 == 0, "Buzz");

    private final IntFunction<Boolean> isApplicable;
    private final String output;

    FizzBuzz(final IntFunction<Boolean> isApplicable, final String output) {
        this.isApplicable = isApplicable;
        this.output = output;
    }

    public static String fizzBuzz(int i) {
        final String result = Stream.of(FizzBuzz.values())
                .filter(fb -> fb.apply(i))
                .map(FizzBuzz::getOutput)
                .collect(joining(""));
        if (result.length() > 0) {
            return result;
        }
        return Integer.toString(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean apply(int value) {
        return isApplicable.apply(value);
    }

    public String getOutput() {
        return output;
    }
}
```

Each `enum` value has an `IntFunction<Boolean>` that defines whether it's applicable to the current number. The `enum` also has its magic `String` to output.

We define a method `fizzBuzz` that uses a `Stream` to:

- loop over the `enum` values in order
- check if the `enum` is applicable
- transform it to its magic `String`
- join all matching values on `""` - i.e. just join them
- if the result is non-empty return the result, otherwise return the number

So use we just need to set up a `Stream` if numbers and process each with `FizzBuzz.fizzBuzz` and output the results:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20)
        .mapToObj(FizzBuzz::fizzBuzz)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This solution is very easily extensible to more conditions (divisors of `7` etc.). Your solution uses brute forced permutations rather than concatenation so using your logic you would have exponentially more tests for each new item.

A `switch` is used for a different situation, usually to *replace* chained `if...else` statements, not **in addition** to them.

Comment: Isn't this solution a little overcomplicated?

Comment: @FabioMarcolini I was trying to demonstrate that `switch` is completely the wrong approach. This approach is complicated, yes, but for a reason. It also looks longer than it is - it's mostly Java boilerplate; once you remove the constructors and the getters... The OP's `switch` approach is complicated for _no_ reason.

Comment: Sorry, but apart from the excessive length, I'd recommend it for Code Golf. While the OP's `switch` makes no sense, it may make it clearer in other situations. These functional stuff may, too, but only in very specific situations and otherwise it does a lot of harm. @FabioMarcolini Java 8 has become the unique way to write a few Java lines that nobody can understand.

Answer (score 2):

Few notes:

- Initialization of `status` is not required.
- Default status is 4, so the default case should be case 4.
- Precalculate and store the result instead of calculating at each step:

  ```
  int status = (((fbNumber%fizz==0)<<1) | ((fbNumber%buzz==0)<<1)) + 1;
  ```
- Consider using `enum`:

  ```
  public enum Status{
      FbStatusFizzBuzz("FizzBuzz"),
      FbStatusFizz("Fizz"),
      FBStatusBuzz("Buzz"),
      FBStatusDefault("Default")
      ;

      private final String status;

      Status(final String status) {
          this.status = status;
      }

      public String getStatus() {
          return this.status;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

*(Very late to the party so just a very partial answer stating some general rules)*

Why so complicated? My one-liner does the job as well:

> System.out.print("1\n2\nFizz\n4\nBuzz\nFizz\n7\n8\nFizz\nBuzz\n11\nFizz\n13\n14\nFizzBuzz\n16\n17\nFizz\n19\nBuzz\nFizz\n22\n23\nFizz\nBuzz\n26\nFizz\n28\n29\nFizzBuzz\n31\n32\nFizz\n34\nBuzz\nFizz\n37\n38\nFizz\nBuzz\n41\nFizz\n43\n44\nFizzBuzz\n46\n47\nFizz\n49\nBuzz\nFizz\n52\n53\nFizz\nBuzz\n56\nFizz\n58\n59\nFizzBuzz\n61\n62\nFizz\n64\nBuzz\nFizz\n67\n68\nFizz\nBuzz\n71\nFizz\n73\n74\nFizzBuzz\n76\n77\nFizz\n79\nBuzz\nFizz\n82\n83\nFizz\nBuzz\n86\nFizz\n88\n89\nFizzBuzz\n91\n92\nFizz\n94\nBuzz\nFizz\n97\n98\nFizz\nBuzz\n");

Now seriously: Is yours any better? Not much, but it could be, just follow these rules (using other answers):

- Whenever you wrote a method doing both computation and output, you did it wrong as it's not reusable for anything else.
- Try to write methods returning a result to be used later (only when everything is done, print the results).

Make some nice building blocks like

```
FBStatus classify(int number) {...}

String fizzBuzzString(int number, FBStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
        case FIZZ: return "Fizz";
        case BUZZ: return "Buzz";
        case FIZZBUZZ: return "FizzBuzz";
        case NONE: return Integer.toString(number);
    }
}
```

compose them to bigger building blocks

```
String fizzBuzzString(int number) {
    return fizzBuzzString(number, classify(number));
}
```

and you get all the flexibility you may need later.

---

As already stated, using the switch means doubling the effort as you're first branching on the numbers and then on the status, which could with less effort done in one go.

In some cases, performance matters, in others, doing this makes it clearer without losing any significant speed. As fizzbuzz is too trivial, there's no clear answer here.

---

If I was to optimize, I'd go for something like

```
private static final String[] MOD15 = {
    "FizzBuzz", null, null,
    "Fizz", null, "Buzz",
    "Fizz", null, null,
    "Fizz", "Buzz", null,
    "Fizz", null, null,
};

String fizzBuzzString(int number) {
    String result = MOD15[number % 15];
    return result!=null ? result : Integer.toString(number);
}
```

but optimizations are rarely needed and that's a different story.

Comment: `FBStatus` first thing that pops in my mind was Facebook status.(I'm a bit sad of myself :P)